# How to get parameter name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a url something like that:

> //my-url-adresses.com/web/Assets/js/javascripts?v=5.2&marker=2017-05/logo_30dKmOHPNLq8CfiOYfqhmarkerv2.png&cdn=//cdn.mywebsite.com/files/

and I want to get this part: (after cdn=):

> //cdn.mywebsite.com/files/

I have provided my code below. Please correct where i am wrong. Thanks in advance.

```js
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var index = scripts.length - 1;
var myScript = scripts[index];
var scripturl = myScript.src;
var cdnUrl = getParameterByName("cdn", scripturl);
var markerUrl = getParameterByName("marker", scripturl);


function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


console.log(markerUrl);
```

```html
<script id="scripts" src="//my-url-adresses.com/web/Assets/js/javascripts?v=5.2&amp;marker=2017-05/logo_30dKmOHPNLq8CfiOYfqhmarkerv2.png&amp;cdn=//cdn.mywebsite.com.com/files/" defer></script>
```

Comment: where is code for `getParameterByName`

Comment: you can not find paramater as this, you use find method via indexof() method ,check this @Avi Flax answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: I'm looking for a my mistake @Justinas

Comment: How about getParameterByName function? Can you write?

Comment: now I see my getParameterFunction() is broken that's why is not working thanks guys

Comment: We are still to see your broken `getParameterFunction()`

Comment: guys thank but I'm looking for a my mistake yes I know but as youu see my function is not working I just request the check my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that your code is not able to access the script url using the index property. I also noticed you have id in your script tag. It would be better to use that, otherwise if you have some script tag with some function in your page at the bottom of page, it would get those(since you are finding the last script tag in the page) and since it don't have `src` it won't fetch result.

Here is a solution using `getElementById()`

```js
var myScript = document.getElementById('scripts');
var scripturl = myScript.src;
var cdnUrl = getParameterByName("cdn", scripturl);
var markerUrl = getParameterByName("marker", scripturl);


function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url);
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


console.log(markerUrl);
```

```html
<script id="scripts" src="//my-url-adresses.com/web/Assets/js/javascripts?v=5.2&amp;marker=2017-05/logo_30dKmOHPNLq8CfiOYfqhmarkerv2.png&amp;cdn=//cdn.anitur.com/web/" defer></script>
```

Comment: bravo very well

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   var myScript = document.getElementById('scripts');
var scripturl = myScript.src; // or window.location.href for current url
    var captured = /cdn=([^&]+)/.exec(scripturl )[1];  
    var result = captured ? captured : 'myDefaultValue';
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you Uphar but it didn't work for this scripts tag:
`<script id="scripts" src="//my-url-adresses.com/web/Assets/js/javascripts?v=5.2&amp;marker=2017-05/logo_30dKmOHPNLq8CfiOYfqhmarkerv2.png&amp;cdn=//cdn.anitur.com/web/" defer></script>`

Comment: edited answer..